# What do we know about Khadgi, the wife of nirrta?

Tags: demi-god

All of the gods are extensively covered but khadgi wasnt found anywhere. What do we know about her?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425635.html#note-t-157673 in 106th point , khadgi has been referred to as one of the 1000 epithets of lord vishnu.

But here https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122489.html  khadgi isn't mentioned.

Regarding khadgi being wife of nirrta - I couldn't find any reference. There is confusion regrading nirrta also as nirrti is mentioned in vedas ( https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10059.htm) (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av05007.htm) in shatapatha brahamana (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe41/sbe4110.htm

But in vayu purana suddenly nirrta appears as one of the rudras (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225958.html see in footnotes)

then here nirrta is lord of southwest (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423750.html)

So its difficult to tell which is correct or incoorect